# Executing easyrsa sign-req script in batch mode

Tags: vpn, batch, rsa

I'm building a component that would automatically generate certs for a VPN connection and pass them to the client. Is there a way to give the CA passphrase to the `easyrsa` `sign-req` script in a non-interactive way *(echoing the pass phrase did not work for me)*?

Comment: That should never be done, unless the CA key is being protected via an unexploitable method. Providing a CA passphrase in the way asked is essentially compromising the VPN from the start - bad idea all around.

Comment: It is not my case. the pass phrase and CA key never leaves the host. My task is to automate creation of ovpn conf files. Anyway, I have managed to accomplish that using expect. Thanks

Comment: Point taken, and I fully understand your concern, but you are not fully aware for what purpose this infrastructure is being created. It is being done as ad-hoc measure to service remote IoT device in case something fails.